# Issue in fetching Time data type of MySQL using JDBC client

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**MySQL version** : 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

---

As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html), max value of Time is "838:59:59"

I inserted this value in table named `table01` having 1 **Time** column `col_time`.

I tried to fetch this using Java JDBC code:

```
public class JDBCUtil {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/testdb";

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();) {

            String sql = "select * from table01;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Time time = rs.getTime("col_time");
                System.out.print("col_time : " + time);

            }
            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I got exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time '838:59:59' in column 1
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimeFast(ResultSetRow.java:949)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getTimeFast(ByteArrayRow.java:226)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimeInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6050)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTime(ResultSetImpl.java:5784)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTime(ResultSetImpl.java:5819)
>       at com.impetus.idw.blend.utils.JDBCUtil.main(JDBCUtil.java:34)

**This is expected as exceeding limit of `java.sql.Time`**

Then I fetched it as String using

```
while (rs.next()) {
        String time = rs.getString("col_time");
        System.out.print("col_time : " + time);
    }
```

I got exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time '838:59:59' in column 1
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimeFromString(ResultSetImpl.java:5975)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5723)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5610)
>       at com.impetus.idw.blend.utils.JDBCUtil.main(JDBCUtil.java:37)

How can I fetch **Time** field? What am I missing here?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1330069?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What is the format of Time? Could you try importing a different time datatype? Check out this link: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefsqlj21908.html

Comment: Here is a another link with the format of `Time` variable: http://forcedotcom.github.io/phoenix/datatypes.html#time_type

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal I did not get your point. I have data provided by the customer. I can't change the data type. I want to read this data using JDBC.

Comment: Where exactly is the error in your code? While line?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal I mentioned exceptions clearly in the question

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal I am executing SQL query on a table containing Time datatype and get value from ResultSet as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the MySQL JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) indicates that TIME fields are *always* converted to `java.sql.Time`. A look at the source code shows that this is indeed true - even when you call `getString()` it first retrieves the data as `Time`, and then gives you its string representation.

Your solution should be to let the database convert the time value to string before you fetch it. That is, instead of just using `SELECT *`, use

```
SELECT CAST( col_time AS char ) AS col_time_str
FROM table01
```

And then use `rs.getString("col_time_str")`.

Mysql will convert the time field to a string for you, and you'll be able to retrieve it like you do any `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the time column using query ,you can modify the query as

```
String sql = "select TIME_FORMAT(col_time,'%H:%i:%i') as col_time from table01;";
```

In this query, mysql specific TIME_FORMAT() function is used which will format the col_time according to the format passed. For more info regarding this and similar date time functions, refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

Answer (score 0):

The format for the `Time` variable is: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss. This is different than what the SQL database is storing so maybe it isn't compatible when you try initialising `time` as the selected time. The docs say:

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or 'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values).

Since there are different formats your `time` variable doesn't get initialised.

What you could try is this:
Store the retrieved time from your database as a `String`. Then use the answer of the following link to cha

Comment: I think you have not read the documentation of `java.sql.Time`. Also, probably haven't read the question, as the OP asks why using `getString()` gives him an exception about time format.